# Plugin on view button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i am developing a plugin which will have two buttons (launch and preview button), the launch button works when user clicked to allow him/her to clone an app to the server. Codes below for launch button:

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="server_id" value="<?php echo $server_id; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="<?php echo $app_id; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="launch_clone" value="doit">
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
            <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">Launch</button>
        </form>
```

That one above works fine,but i want the preview button once clicked to take user to view template or image without editing. Here are the codes for view button:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="view_template" value="<?php echo $app_id; ?>">
        onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()"
        <button class="submit">Preview</button>
    </form>
```

Anyone out there who can help?

Comment: information in  html part is not enough

Comment: You have an error in second form. . input element not closed properly